# JUnit wait before proceeding

Tags: junit, java-8

I am relying on some third party API to perform some action, namely delete a user eg. `user.delete()`. Unfortunately this is a void return and doesn't give me anything like a `CompletableFuture` back.

This is causing me some problems in my integration testing as I wish to create a user in a number of tests and then delete it once the test is complete ready for the next one. The test won't run if the delete task has not been completed by the third party.

So I can think of two solutions in my test code

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Yuck quite brittle I have no idea how long it will take. Or block until I can be sure the user no longer exists (ResourceException thrown when user doesn't exist)

```
private void blockUntilUserRemoved() {
    try {
        do {
            servicesClient.getUser("donald.duck@disney.com");
        } while (true);
    } catch (ResourceException e) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Which will work but feels wrong using exceptions to control the logic like this. Question is does it matter in test code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is as much as you can do with a `void` return type. So basically you do a long pooling here and check if it has been really deleted.

Other things I can think off is *may be* a database trigger that would work on delete - no idea if it is possible though; but even if it is - for tests this would require quite a lot of work. Another thing is that may be you can do that in a separate thread and your main thread get updated whenever the result comes - but again, for tests this sounds like an overkill, to me.

Another small suggestion is `Thread.onSpinWait` (since java-9) - read it's documentation to see how it might help (a bit).